# Use native document picture scanner from the web

Tags: javascript, android-camera, ocr, ios-camera

I am building a web application that needs to have document scanner functionalities. I made some research to do that fully with web technologies but it seems that it's a bit too complicated for what I need. Is it possible from within a web app to open ios Notes document scanner or Drive document scanner and receive the data the same way that it's possible to use the native camera?
Basically I need to open camera with document scanning mode, that way the document recognition and framing will be done with the native functionality and only my web app to save it.